# how can i fix this filter function till it works?

Tags: php, if-statement, search, logic, conditional-statements

soo.. i want to make filter function on my website that, he use 3 tables tb_data,tb_peserta, and paket to print out the tables component on yhis page

```
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
$query = "
    SELECT 
        tb_peserta.id_peserta,
        tb_data.nama,
        tb_paket.nama_paket,
        ket,
        waktu_awal,
        waktu_akhir
    FROM 
        tb_peserta,tb_data,tb_paket 
    WHERE  
        tb_peserta.id_number=tb_data.id_number 
        AND tb_peserta.id_paket=tb_paket.id_paket 
        AND status_data_peserta='aktif' 
        AND nama LIKE '%$keyword%' 
        OR nama_paket LIKE '%$keyword%' 
        OR ket LIKE '%$keyword'
";
```

that is the filter query that ive made.. this not showing a data but it show all data, its not work.. so ineed ur help

Comment: Can you show some sample data of the tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite possible that you have created a Cartesian join here.   I would recommend using ansi style sql, as it is much clearer and is not so susceptible to unexpected join results:

```
SELECT 
    tb_peserta.id_peserta,tb_data.nama,tb_paket.nama_paket,ket,waktu_awal,waktu_akhir
FROM 
    tb_peserta
    INNER JOIN tb_data on tb_peserta.id_number=tb_data.id_number
    INNER JOIN tb_paket on tb_peserta.id_paket = tb_paket.id_paket
WHERE 
    status_data_peserta='aktif'
    — note parentheses and placeholders!
    AND (
        nama LIKE ?
        OR
        nama_paket LIKE ?
        OR
        ket LIKE ?
    )
```

Two important things to note:

1. When you use `and` and `or` together, you can get unexpected results if you do not clarify the operation order with parentheses
2. Never ever put a variable in your query using concatenation. Always use prepared statements. (The `?` you see). For reference, see this website on how to use [PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)